# I was extending an ntfs partition in gparted and right in the middle of the process, power went out

Tags: ubuntu, partition, ntfs

I was extending an ntfs partition in gparted and right in the middle of the process, power went out.
Now my files can't be opened though I can still see they exist in the partition. I went to see if there was a problem of mounting in gparted but instead I found a red symbol in front of the disk name and when I try to check the partition as the warning message suggests, the checking process just freezes gparted and I am prompted with a "force quit" message.
Please help me I am surely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Windows system to force a check/fix on the filesystem.

If you don't have Windows I would question why you're using NTFS at all.

Comment: why I use ntfs is because as I was trying to dual boot windows and ubuntu, I was unable to boot back to windows and the ntfs partition I was using was still mounted as ntfs. I assume mounting it to a different file type could cause data loss, right?

Comment: I really need help please if you can

Comment: My help in is in my answer. Use Windows to force a check on the filesystem. If it can't help then you'll need to restore from [your backup](https://gparted.org/faq.php#faq-6)

Comment: but I don't have windows

Comment: *but I don't have windows* AGAIN, if you don't have Windows you shouldn't be using NTFS, end of story.